# Sin flecha de ubicación en google map api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, api

Con este fragmento de codigo obtengo mi ubicación:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Maps1.this,
            new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Pero solo obtengo la ubicación con un circulo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy intentando es esto, pero no se si me falta la instrucción para habilitar la brújula del dispositivo.

```
UiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal, obtengo la ubicación mas no orientación.

Lo que quiero lograr es eso:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes revisar la documentación oficial de google maps para Android
Te dejo el siguiente enlace en donde te proporciona información parecida a lo que buscas que seria la Inclinación de la cámara para el mapa. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views?hl=es-419 Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Debajo de la línea:

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Añade la siguiente linea de código:

```
UiSettings uiSettings = googleMap.getUiSettings();
uiSettings.setCompassEnabled(false);
```

Esta solución la encontré en el siguiente **[enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146514/unable-to-display-map-in-android)**